# Are there any comparable frameworks to dynaTrace that are open source?

Tags: java, performance, testing, architecture

I like dynaTrace tool and wondering if there are any open source alternatives to this library.

Answer (score 5):

Apdex
Java APM tools
insideApps
[open source APM](http://www.getapp.com/software-system/Open-source/application-performance-management-software)
[other one](http://www.capterra.com/application-performance-management-software?submit.x=30&submit.y=22&platform%5B4%5D=4&users=0&location=0&revenue=0&employees=0&budget=)
[also](http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/articles/apm1b.shtml)
[helios](http://www.heliosdev.org/helios-apm)
[infrared](http://infrared.sourceforge.net/versions/latest/)
[listen to this videos it may help](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ox9QtYxipPo&feature=player_embedded)